# Extract from Oracle to SQL Server causing failures and incorrect row counts

Tags: sql-server, oracle, extract, oledb

I have a SQL Server extract that is pulling data from an Oracle Database.  The issue I'm having seems a bit off.

There is a single column in the query based on a left join that once I added it in, either

A) The extract just fails without giving any type of an error message in the job history

B) The wrong number of records is imported (i.e. running the query directly though oracle shows a return count of 2000 rows and I get 1895 on import).

Removing the join and the column resolves the issue, but unfortunately it is information I have to have.  I've researched this some online and about the only information I found (something about adding to the connection string) did not solve the issue. I have also tried to account for any problems that could arise due to having null values in the column by adding a CASE statement in the extract query like this (is it a GUID value that is causing the problem, please note the pseudo code):

```
,CASE
    WHEN oracle.guid IS NULL
    THEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(oracle.guid, '{', ''), '}', '') 
 END AS sql.guid
```

As you can see here I am performing a replace in the query as the Source value is bracketed and the destination values needs to have these removed.

This is coming from Oracle 12C to SQL Server 2016.  The connection is being made with the OraOLEDB12.dll provided from the ODAC installer package.

Comment: As a note, here is the only bit of online information that I found that seemed relevant to the issue I'm having and it did not resolve the problem: https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2012/9/2/resolving-missing-records-in-ssis-from-oracle-source.html

Comment: I would perform the extract using an `ORDER BY` clause to guarantee that it's always returned in the same order and see how many rows are successfully imported. After that, I'd run the query directly in Oracle to see which is the row exactly past the row sucessfully inserted and check if there's anything wrong with that Guid.

Comment: I know this is SQL Server 2014 related, but does the suggested workaround work for you? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157005/sql-server-odbc-linked-server-to-oracle-does-not-return-all-rows

Comment: @Boneist I will have to check and see if that solves the problem.  Not only are they using SQL Server 2014, but they are also using a linked server where I am not.  Also, they cited that the issue was with Oracle columns where it was a precision non-specific number problem, where my column is a varchar().

Comment: @Icarus,  I've attempted something similar to this.  I already have it ordered by a specific column.  The issue I was having was selecting a specific row number in Oracle.  I suppose I could export it to a temp table, adding a row count column and then selecting by that...any other ways you can think of?

Comment: @JasonWH apart from looking at the logs, I don't have any other suggestions at the moment, but you mentinoned that the logs don't show anything...

Comment: @Icarus I did as you suggested.  It's been stopping (when it completes) at row 254790 out of about 261100.  I checked the entries for rows 254790, 254791, and 254792 in the source and they all look the same.  I'll go through the logs one more time but yes, the job history is not showing anything.

Comment: @JasonWH I have jobs that copy 600K records every two hours from SS to Oracle. Another that copies those same records from Oracle to a different SS (after manipulation is done). I use database links on the Oracle side, Linked Servers on the SS side. I have found that it is best to select from tables, views, or table functions without any joins in the select statement. A lot of issues are avoided by not using those joins. Keep all of your select processing in one database.